# How can I add an extension that uses the internal Gollum markdown processor?

Tags: ruby, gollum-wiki

- Description:

  - I am trying to integrate a workflow and tools which incorporates vimwiki and Gollum. I want to merely add vimwiki as an extention type for the editor while being processed by Gollum's internal Markdown processor (see "Things I've tried" #1).
  - Eventually I'd also like to have Gollum default to 'vimwiki' when creating new documents as well.
  - The project I'm working on can be found at [Vimwiki-Gollum-Integration](https://github.com/karlredman/Vimwiki-Gollum-Integration)
- Testing Specifics:

  - Gollum version: 4.1.1
  - The file being tested is valid github markdown
  - The same content is being tested with different filenames and extensions:

    - testx.thing
    - blah.vimwiki
  - The test files do work fine when they are named with .md extensions
  - relevant rendering gems installed:

    - github-markdown
    - github-markup
    - kramdown
    - redcarpet
  - All code is being tested in a gollum --config  file
  - I'm not well versed in ruby

### Things I've tried

1. Creating a new extension and custom renderer

   - This works except there is no reason to implement a custom processor (pandoc)
   - This would be ideal so that the Markdown name ends up in the Edit page. However, I don't think I should have to involve pandoc here
   - How in the heck do I get the edit page to default the markdown to vimwiki when editing a vimwiki extension?
   - file used: blah.vimwiki

```rb
# always include this:
Gollum::Page.send :remove_const, :FORMAT_NAMES if defined? Gollum::Page::FORMAT_NAMES

################### custom extension + renderer
# # Custom extension rendering
# ## References
# * file reference: /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/github-markup-1.6.0/lib/github/markup/command_implementation.rb
# * [Adding Pandoc to Gollum - Martin Wolf's weblog [OUTDATED]](https://www.mwolf.net/2014/04/29/adding-pandoc-to-gollum/)
ci = ::GitHub::Markup::CommandImplementation.new(
     /vimwiki/,
     ["Vimwiki"],
     "pandoc -f markdown-tex_math_dollars-raw_tex",
     :vimwiki)

# bind your own extension regex (the new set of extensions will also include `.asc` and `.adoc`):
# # * file reference: /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/github-markup-1.6.0/lib/github/markups.rb
Gollum::Markup.register(:vimwiki,  "Vimwiki")
Gollum::Markup.formats[:vimwiki][:regexp] = /vimwiki/
GitHub::Markup::markup_impl(:vimwiki, ci)
##################
```

2. Attempt to replace the Markdown primary extension and regex.

   - I don't understand why this isn't working unless I'm misunderstanding the order of operations for matching and overrides.
   - The page will display, the extension is recognized, but the page does not format at all -scrunches everything together.

```rb
# always include this:
Gollum::Page.send :remove_const, :FORMAT_NAMES if defined? Gollum::Page::FORMAT_NAMES

# Attempt to replace the primary extension for Markdown
# remove the original markdown binding:
Gollum::Markup.formats.delete(:markdown)

# and define your own 
Gollum::Markup.formats[:thing] = {
    :name => "Markdown",
    :regexp => /thing/
}
```

3. Attempt to just replace the markdown extension regex

   - Same result as attempt 2.
   - The page will display but it is not formatted correctly

```rb
# always include this:
Gollum::Page.send :remove_const, :FORMAT_NAMES if defined? Gollum::Page::FORMAT_NAMES

Gollum::Markup.formats[:markdown][:regexp] = /vimwiki|thing/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm closing the question:

As it turns out there is no way easy way to use the markdown processor and also get the edit page to recognize that there is a different extension. The markdown processor requires the extension to be valid it it's regex of extensions found in [markdown.rb](https://github.com/github/markup/blob/master/lib/github/markup/markdown.rb).

The bottom line is that I would need to implement something similar to what pandoc is doing anyway. So I'm just going just drop the subject and stick with pandoc -'Things I've tried #1' from the original question.

Rather than take a bunch of space here I've posted the documentation on the [project page](https://github.com/karlredman/Vimwiki-Gollum-Integration/tree/2a9c90b037fa1d43f1190729ba336f15c2265bd5) with code examples

Thank you to whomever spent some time thinking about this.